# Limit of sum of squares of sine

Tags: limits

I am trying to get $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {\sin^{2}1 + \sin^{2}2 + \dots \sin^{2}n \over n}$. I get stuck on rewriting the numerator using trig identities. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Use $\cos(2x)$ and sum of cosines.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin^2i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2i)=\frac{1}{2}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin(2n+1)}{\sin1}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll explain in more detail what Ian Miller said. The limit is $\frac 12$ as the sine is bounded. You get the first equality by using $cos(x+y)=\text{cos} (x)\text{cos} (y)-\text{sin}(x)\text{sin}(y)$. The second equality comes from Lagrange's trigonometric identity for sums of cosines.